# how to disable button of one item when other item is clicked in a row in gridlayout

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, grid-layout, qabstractitemview

I want, that when the user click on the button of left item, certain function happens and the button on the right got disable, same vice versa with other button on the  right.

Videoview is inside the recyclerView, placed with the help of gridviewLayout with Spancount 2.

[here the image describing it more nicely, have a look to understand properly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQNqF.jpg)

please help me.

Comment: Where is the code that isn't working for you?

Comment: I have not written the code yet, i don't know where to start from, want someone to guide me that how should i go.